# How to use cache or local storage?

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-storage

I am developing an android application using restful webservices. I get all data from server to my app. It always take some time to load the data from server to app activity.How to sync some data to local database and show while app is offline.
 please help me.
Thankyou in Advance.

Comment: On first laucning the app get the app and then store in memory and all the way use the data from memory rather calling web service every time

Comment: Any example please

Comment: The example will be too broad.you can have a look at the tutorial those are easily available over google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following ways to store app data:

1. SQLite : It is a opensource SQL database that stores data to a text file on a device. Android comes in with built in SQLite database implementation. Hence it is rather easy to use.

Go through this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) from Developer site for reference.

2. Shared Preferences : SharedPreferences are used to save data based on key-value pair.
   A preference file is actually a xml file saved in internal memory of device. 
   Every application have some data stored in memory in a directory 
   so whenever getSharedPreferences(String name,int mode) function get called it validates the file that if it exists or it doesn’t 
   then a new xml is created with passed name.

Go through this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) from Developer site for reference.

3. Internal Storage: This method is specifically for those situations where you need to store data to the device filesystem, but you do not want any other app (even the user) to read this data. Note that this data is deleted from the device when your app is uninstalled.

Go through this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage) from Developer site for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use database like room or sqlite for caching the data. And check the condition wheater it is coming from server are stored from database.

Comment: Any example please

Comment: https://github.com/pthakkar9/Android-Example-on-SQLite-and-Retrofit

Answer (score 1):

A few good answer are already given here such as:
- SQLite 
- Shared Preferences
- internal storage

But for reference try to avoid "internal storage" because it requires a special permission from the user and is at best, only used for document or image type files.

Sqlite is the best way to store lots of information on your phone locally but sinds a few years google has created "android jet pack" with "Room" an Sqlite db framework that makes implementing a SQLite db really easy.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/

If you don't want to use offline storage, you can always add caching to your https responces.
the volley library from google has this build in for you

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/